# When starting server (rails s) Don't know how to build task 'deploy' (see --tasks) (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I am getting the error when starting the server `rails s` in my local environment.

I tried to google , but all these `capistrano` Dont know how to build tasks are all ***deploy*** related, not when starting server in local environment.

I am not sure either whether its a rails or capistrano issue.

Here is the link of the trace. [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Iqlaas/c7083cbdb10604a66008e4dc00ff5ef8).

Any help is appreciated!

**[application.rb](https://gist.github.com/Iqlaas/eaca80744ff4d2dab7628372abb1f43c)**

Comment: Could you show me this file ? /Users/KamalIqlaas/Desktop/bateriku/bateriku-web/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: Thanks @WillNguyen , updated the question.

Comment: Somebody had same issue: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3484

Comment: I suspect that you used to use Capistrano but you removed something so that deploy task can't involve references. Let's check if Capistrano is still put in development group. Performing bundle install to make sure didn't miss any gems. As you can see in error shown, the issue related to gems. In addition, it pointed out the issue occurred at Bundler.require(*Rails.groups) => double-check your gemfile.

Comment: From examples here: http://bundler.io/v1.5/groups.html I can only assume that You've problems with one or more gems inside gem group. Try to remove one by one and run to find the issue. Or do as @WillNguyen said: `Performing bundle install to make sure didn't miss any gems. `

Comment: Thanks WillNguyen and @num8er, but i did bundle install already before posting this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have Capistrano-related gems in your Gemfile but have not marked them as `require: false`. As a result, when Rails boots up, it tries to load all of that Capistrano code, which is not how Capistrano is intended to be used.

In your case it looks like the `capistrano-gitflow` gem is the culprit. Always use `require: false` for it and all other Capistrano-related gems in the Gemfile, like this:

```
gem "capistrano", "~> 3.10", require: false
gem "capistrano-bundler", require: false
gem "capistrano-rails", require: false
```

The fact that this is not explained in the Capistrano documentation is an oversight that I will try to get corrected.

Comment: Thanks, The Creator. However, I add `require: false` only to `capistrano-gitflow`, and it worked. And I have no idea why.

Comment: The official Capistrano gems have been written in such that they shouldn't cause problems if you require them by accident. The same cannot be said for third-party gems from the community like capistrano-gitflow. To play it safe, I recommend always using `require: false`.

Comment: Yes, thats the reason. Third party gem. You are a great help, appreciate it Mr Brictson.